# Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'tum_ardrone'

Tags: ubuntu, tum-ardrone, ros-fuerte, rosmake, ubuntu-precise

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosmake ardrone_autonomy is ok, but **rosmake tum_ardrone** has problem. All source from **wiki.ros.org/tum_ardrone**.

My error is showed as follows:

{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cd thirdparty && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone/thirdparty' making third party libs cd libcvd && make make[2]: Entering directory` /home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/libcvd'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'. make[2]: Leaving directory` /home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/libcvd'
cd gvars3 && make
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/gvars3' make[2]: Nothing to be done for` all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone/thirdparty/gvars3' make[1]: Leaving directory` /home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone/thirdparty'
make -f Makefile_package
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone' mkdir -p bin cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package tum_ardrone
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests tum_ardrone
[rospack] Error: package/stack tum_ardrone depends on non-existent package tld_tracker

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'tum_ardrone'.
Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:16 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/yaya/fuerte_workspace/tum_ardrone'

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package tum_ardrone written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/yaya/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20140612-113318/tum_ardrone/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tum_ardrone [FAIL] [ 0.10 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package tum_ardrone.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 27 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory

**I just start to use ROS, and spend a lot of time to this problem above, but still can't solve this error. Plase help me, thank you in advance.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173463/failed-to-invoke-rospack-to-get-compile-flags-for-package-%27tum_ardrone%27/) by [yaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/18851/yaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just some quick thoughts:

1. You are using fuerte. Are you certain that you downloaded the fuerte-branch of the ardrone_driver (Not the tum_ardrone)?
2. If I recall correctly, you had to compile the SDK seperatly first, before invoking ROS commands. Did you do that?
3. Could you reformat your question such that all your command line output is formatted? :)

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/18851/yaya/) on 2014-06-13**:
Thank you for your reply. I have solved this problem today. It's something wrong about tum_ardrone package and I fix it. Thank you again!

**Comment by [sandra](https://answers.ros.org/users/21637/sandra/) on 2015-02-14**:
@yaya - COuld you please tell me what the problem with tum_ardrone was and what changes I should do? I am facing the same problem, and can't figure out the solution. Thank you